# how to add web reference in MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

on MS CRM 4.0, we can add this web service as web reference:
http:///MSCrmServices/2007/CrmService.asmx

to get all CRM entities to our local,

actually i just want to create a class library project and add web reference to CRM web service, and get all original and my customized entities?

i knew the tool cmrsvcutil.exe (in CRMSDK) can generate all entities (includes customized), but the code is only for .NET 4.0.

can anybody help me?

*UPDATE***

finally i used CRMSDK4 and DynamicEntity to call CRM web service and update my customized eneties.

Answer (score 4):

The CRM 2011 SDK is built on .NET 4 so you may have some trouble if you are working with an earlier version.  Can you explain a little more about your application and needs as their are more web services in the 2011 version than there were in 4.  It is best practice to use the SDK libraries to reference the service.  If you want to use pre .NET 4 I would recommend using the CRM 4 SDK to connect to the CRM 4 endpoint that still exists for backwards compatibility.  Note that this isn't a great solution in the long run as the next version likely will not support use of the CRM 4 web service.

To see the new 2011 service endpoints, log in to CRM, click on Settings > Customization > Developer Resources ->
[image]